# How to fill empty places with images according to situation

Tags: react-native

*I have algorithm problem. I send Image uri to this component from another component. In touchableopacity I have default img but when this.state.img is not null, I want to change touchableopacity's image.*

**Image places like this :**

[image]

*When I send image here, I want to fill first place, If i send second time I want it go second place. This should go like this.  For example first 3 slot full, if I remove second image and send image here again, I want to fill second place because second image place will be free. 
How do I can this ?.*

```
render() {

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                <View style={{ width: '24%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        {
                                this.rend()
                        }
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

                <View style={{ width: '24%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity >
                          {
                                this.rend()
                          }
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
                </View>

                <View style={{ width: '24%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity >
                       {
                                this.rend()
                        }
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
)
}
```

**this is method:**

```
rend() {

    if (this.props.img === '')
    {
       return <View style={{ height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', aspectRatio: 1 }}>
                    <Image source={this.state.defaultImage} style={{ height: '90%', width: '90%' }} />      
              </View>
        }
    else
    {
        return <View style={{ height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', aspectRatio: 1 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.props.img }} style={{ height: '90%', width: '90%' }} />      
                </View>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const N_BUTTONS = 4;
const DEFAULT_IMG_URL = require('../Images/addcircle.png');

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This create an empty array that you can map over:
    const imgUrls = Array.apply(null, Array(N_BUTTONS));
    this.state = {
      imgUrls,
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { img: newImgUrl } = nextProps;
    const { img: imgUrl } = this.props;

    if (newImgUrl && newImgUrl !== imgUrl) {
      const { imgUrls } = this.state;
      // Take a copy to force refresh after setting state:
      const imgUrlsClone = imgUrls.slice(0);

      for (let i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i += 1) {
        if (!imgUrlsClone[i]) {
          imgUrlsClone[i] = newImgUrl;
          break;
        }
      }

      this.setState({ imgUrls: imgUrlsClone });
    }
  }

  removeImg = (imgIndex) => {
    const { imgUrls } = this.state;
    const imgUrlsClone = imgUrls.slice(0);

    imgUrlsClone[imgIndex] = null;

    this.setState({ imgUrls: imgUrlsClone });
  };

  renderContent = () => {
    const { imgUrls } = this.state;
    console.log('imgUrls', imgUrls.length);

    return imgUrls.map((url, index) => {
      // ex for url = require('../Images/image1.png')
      const uri = url || DEFAULT_IMG_URL;

      return (
        <View key={index}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image source={uri} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>{this.renderContent()}</View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to react-native, Can I ask what is difference between const { img: newImgUrl } = nextProps; and . const { img: imgUrl } = this.props;? When I send image, const { img: newImgUrl } = nextProps;doesn't come empty  but   const { img: imgUrl } = this.props; comes empty. why ?

Comment: `nextProps` is a new set of props your component is about to receive , but `this.props` is the current set of props your component already have... if `const { img: imgUrl } = this.props;` is empty, that means your component has not reaceived any `img` prop yet

`componentWillReceiveProps` event is executed just before the `render` method...

Comment: I want to ask a few question about this :). firstly I really dont understand how İmgUrlClone fill in componentWillReceiveProps. And my default image is not shown. I do like this : source={{ uri: url } || this.state.defaultImage} view comes me empty like this.  This is my state:    this.state = {
          imgUrls: new Array(N_BUTTONS),
          defaultImage: require('../Images/addcircle.png'),
        };

Comment: @hakan I edited the the code to make it kind of simpler ... and if anything is not that clear, feel free to comment here, I'll try my best to clarify :)

Comment: Thx for helping :) My buttons have default image but with this code when I send image path to this component, it adds here just with 1 button. But what I want, there should be 4 default button and my images which I send should go those buttons. Your code helped me so much thx for this. But there should be what I mentioned :) I hope I explainrd clearly :)

Comment: Defaultimages not shown in this code. I dont know why.

Comment: @hakan I'll test it on my pc and get back to you :)

Comment: I found mistake but couldnt solve yet, it is about    'imgurls: new Array(N_BUTTONS)',  because of this it doesnt give me my default images. I think because of empty at the beginning

Comment: @hakan check out the edit ... this one should work :)